# Rerendering richfaces rich:columns

Tags: richfaces

I have an extendeddatatable with 'rich:columns value=somelist' in my application.The columns are getting displayed properly initially. But when I add one more item to the 'somelist' and rerender the table, the table is not adding the new column.But if I refresh the page the column will be added.What can be the reason? If any one have any idea please help.

thanks in advance,
deeps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an a4j:commandButton to save to your list?? If yes then you need a reRender to your table.

Comment: Yes, I am using a4j:commandbutton and I have given a rerender for that table.But table is not rerendering.I have one combo box also where I am using the same list and rerendered along with the table.That combo box list is getting added,but not the table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using a4j:commandbutton and I have given a rerender for that table.But table is not rerendering.I have one combo box also where I am using the same list and rerendered along with the table.That combo box list is getting added,but not the table